# SQL Query for retreiving records that fall on the last day of the month

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, dateadd, datepart

I have a table with records from many dates.
I would like to perform a query that only returns records that fall on the last day of the date's month. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE DATEPART(d, mytable.rdate) = DATEPART(d,DATEADD(m,1,DATEADD(d, -1, mytable.rdate)))
```

Except this doesn't work as the `rdate` in the right-hand side of the argument should be the last day of it's month for the `dateadd` to return the correct comparison.

Basically is there an concise way to do this comparison? 
An equivalent for quarter-ends would also be very helpful, but no doubt more complex.

EDIT:

Essentially I want to check if a given date is the last in whatever month (or quarter) it falls into. If it is, return that record. This would involve a some function to return the last day of the month of any date. e.g. `lastdayofmonth('2013-06-10') = 30` (so this record would not be returned.

EDIT2:

For the case of returning the records that fall on the last day of the quarter they are in it would need to be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE DATEPART('d', mytable.rdate) = lastdayofmonth(mytable.rdate)
  AND DATEPART('m', mytable.rdate) = lastmonthofquarter(mytable.rdate);
```

The tricky bit is the `lastdayofmonth()` and `lastmonthofquarter()` functions

Comment: The last date of a month is always one day earlier than the first day of the next month (in the given year).

Comment: yes, the question is how to get there in SQL, preferably without using string manipulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DateSerial Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dateserial-function-HA001228813.aspx) to compute the last day of the month for a given date.

Passing zero as the third argument, *day*, actually returns the last date of the *previous* month.

```vb
rdate = #2013-7-24#
? DateSerial(Year(rdate), Month(rdate), 0)
6/30/2013
```

So to get the last date from the `rdate` month, add `1` to the *month* argument.

```vb
? DateSerial(Year(rdate), Month(rdate) + 1, 0)
7/31/2013
```

You might suspect that approach would break for a December `rdate`, since `Month() + 1` would return 13.  However, `DateSerial` still copes with it.

```vb
rdate = #2013-12-1#
? DateSerial(Year(rdate), Month(rdate) + 1, 0)
12/31/2013
```

If you will be running your query from within an Access application session, you can build a VBA function based on that approach, and use the custom function in the query.

However, if the query will be run from an ODBC or OleDb connection to the Access db, the query can not use a VBA user-defined function.  In that situation, you can use `DateSerial` directly in your query.

```sql
SELECT m.*
FROM mytable AS m
WHERE m.rdate = DateSerial(Year(m.rdate), Month(m.rdate) + 1, 0)
```

That should work if your `rdate` values all include midnight as the time component.  If those values include other times, use `DateValue`.

```sql
WHERE DateValue(m.rdate) = DateSerial(Year(m.rdate), Month(m.rdate) + 1, 0)
```

Comment: That is **exactly** what I was after. Many thanks. As an aside, will this method still work via a prepared query over PDO? I have a webapp that queries my Access Database.

Comment: PDO is ODBC access for PHP, right?  I think DateSerial and those other date functions will still be available when the query is run from ODBC, but you'll have to check.  But ODBC definitely rules out a VBA user-defined function for this.

Comment: Yup, I believe it just uses the ODBC driver. I'll write a quick script and check.

Comment: Just figured out the last day of quarter version: Just add `AND DatePart('m', m.rDate) In(3,6,9,12)` to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: OK, if that gets what you need, another way is `Month(m.rDate) In(3,6,9,12)`  It's slightly more concise, but not a big improvement.  Either way is a simpler route to the last day of quarter than the approach I started working on.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE DATEPART(d, mytable.rdate) = 
DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, this is tested on `MS Access`:

Using `String Concatenation`:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE 
DatePart('d',mytable.rdate) = 
DatePart('d',dateadd('m',1, "1/" & DatePart('m',mytable.rdate)  & "/" & DatePart('yyyy',mytable.rdate))-1);
```

**Update** without using `string concatenation`:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *,
DATEPART('d',DATEDIFF('m',0,mytable.rdate)+1,
DATEADD('m',1,
DATEADD('d',DATEDIFF('d',0,mytable.rdate)- DATEPART('d',mytable.rdate)+1,0))-1) as EOMonth
FROM mytable ) A
WHERE DATEPART('d',mytable.rdate) = DATEPART('d',EOMonth)
```

Comment: Only seems to return 1 record, always from 31 Jan 2013

Comment: Could you show sample data in your post? Do you want to show all end of month regardless of the current date's end of month?

Comment: Afraid I can't show sample data but basically there are many records and they all have different dates, some on month end, some just any day. And yes, I do want to show only dates whose day is the last in its month. The current date's month-end is irrelevant.

Comment: I actually modified your original answer to be your edit (replacing `now()` with `rdate` but it didn't work

Comment: @harryg: I think it is correct except that my format is mm/dd/yyyy and probably yours is dd/mm/yyyy. So, in that regard I changed my answer to your format if ever I am correct. So, try again with my second code.

Comment: Yeah that was the reason, thanks. Although it works I was kind of hoping for a solution that doesn't involve string manipulation so as eliminate problems like the above. Have an upvote but I don't think I want to use it as my answer yet.

Comment: Try my update @harryg this time without using string concatenation.

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't work. Can you explain `DATEDIFF('m',0,mytable.rdate)` as it just returns the number of months between the date epoch and `rdate`, which seems pretty useless.