# MS Access SQL query for testing dates for last day of the quarter

Tags: sql, ms-access

OK, so I have a load of records in a table and they have many different dates.
I want to retern only those records whose date falls on the last day of whatever quarter it's in.

I.e. I basically need the equivalent of a `lastDayOfQuarter(date)` function that calculates the date that is the last day in the quarter for the date passed to it.

e.g. `lastDayOfQuarter(#16/05/2013#) = #30/06/2013#`

My query might look like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE mytable.rdate = lastDayOfQuarter(mytable.rdate);
```

This query will be run over PDO so no VBA allowed. Native MS Access only.
I would also prefer to not use string manipulation as there is a difference between US and EU dates which might cause issues down the line.

Comment: Maybe this gonna help you : [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302452/calculate-the-last-day-of-the-quarter) and also look [HERE](http://www.sqllike.com/sql-server-query-to-find-first-and-last-day-of-month-week-quarter-yea.html)

Comment: Ahem.  You could add `WHERE Month(m.rDate) In(3,6,9,12)` to the query in the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17830458/77335  Nice teamwork there, Harry. :-)

Comment: Yea have done that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering myself as, with the help of [HansUp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77335/hansup) answering a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17830458/1606323) for finding month-end records, I found out quite an easy way to acheive this:

```
WHERE DateValue(m.rdate) = DateSerial(Year(m.rdate), Month(m.rdate) + 1, 0)
  AND Month(m.rdate) IN(3,6,9,12)
```

Answer (score 0):

the "last day of the quarter" could be different for different users.  You may be best to build a table of "lastdays" based on your business rules, then use that table in your query.

Comment: No it wouldn't be different for different users. The last day of a quarter is a fixed, known quantity being the last days of Feb, June, Sep and Dec

Comment: oops, should be march not feb

Comment: But, how your business defines it's quarters could be based on a different fiscal calendar.

Comment: I'm talking about calendar quarters

Answer (score 0):

And here as short answer...Try

```
Select DateAdd(day, -1, dateadd(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, 'year-month-day'), 0))
```

For today it should give you

```
2013-06-30 00:00:00.000
```

SO for your Table you should use :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE mytable.rdate = DateAdd(day, -1, dateadd(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, mytable.rdate), 0));
```